# Doorkeeper gem redirecting to application's home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I am following the video here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper

In this video it has you type something like localhost:3000/oauth/authorize

all works per the video except that if the user is logged in it redirects to localhost:3000

continuing with the tutorial I generate this URL using oauth2 gem:

http://localhost:5000/oauth/authorize?client_id=jp4zY26pXN4SPfQR54ef8j3O2Rxz9T1TRWuvyEZT7cU&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Foneplanet-login-callback&response_type=code

and again hitting this URL just redirects to localhost:5000

Here is my doorkeeper config:

```rb
Doorkeeper.configure do
  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_authenticator do
    Member.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_member_session_url)
  end

  admin_authenticator do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

figured it out.

Others may have the same problem!

the code `Member.find_by(id: session[:user_id])` was returning `nil` so the code was always redirecting.  Changing this to `current_member` fixed it.